# How can i show wordpress post in my codeigniter application?

Tags: database, wordpress, api, codeigniter, rss

I have a WordPress blog site. Also, I am building an application using Codeigniter. I want to show post data from the WordPress blog in my Codeigniter application. I know how to get WordPress post data through DB. But I want to know, How can I show this post data with the feature image through API or RSS feed?

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Wordpress REST api. Check here https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/